# Running npm install with sbt

Tags: node.js, npm, sbt, npm-install

So I have a `sbt` project that uses `sbt-js-engine` and `sbt-webpack` plugins.

It successfully gets and resolves npm packages just fine. And then webpack would build the project.

I have added a npm install script into `package.json` like so,

```
  "scripts": {
    "install": "bower install"
  }
```

However, the problem I am currently having is that when I run webpack (which intern uses [`sbt-js-engine`](https://github.com/stonexx/sbt-webpack) ) it runs `npm update` instead of `npm install`.

Heres an excerpt of my `build.sbt`,

```
lazy val common = project.in(file("common")).
  enablePlugins(SbtWeb).
  settings(
    sourceDirectory in webpack := baseDirectory.value,
    resourceManaged in webpack := (resourceManaged in webpack in root).value,
    includeFilter in webpack := ("*.jsx" || "*.js" || "*.json") && new FileFilter {
      @tailrec
      override def accept(pathname: File): Boolean = {
        if (pathname == null) false
        else if (pathname.getName == "javascripts") true
        else accept(pathname.getParentFile)
      }
    },
    JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node
  )
```

Is there anyway I could run `npm install` instead or even before as a depedency for webpack task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
sourceDirectory in webpack := {
    Process("/usr/local/bin/npm install", file("[path to working dir]")).!
    baseDirectory.value
}
```

That would mean it would run at same time as setting the webpack settings.